# How do I stop a daemon thread that does scheduled database backup ?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I've written a very simple command line programme that uses mysqldump to dump data at a specified interval.
 I wanted it to be running after I run the programme and I disconnect putty ssh connection.
 
But as soon as I exit the ssh connection, the programme shuts down.

I think I can make my programme run even after I disconnected from the ssh by using daemon threads but I'm worried about not being able to find and stop unnecessary duplicate daemon threads.
The scenario I'm decribing is...
1. I log into the server using putty.
2. Turn on the auto backup programme.
3. I exit the putty connection.
---the daemon is running
4. Hopefully, when I log into the server again, I have a way to stop the auto backup programme if needed.

Cron jobs and DBMS specific methods are out of my options.
 I'd like to learn how to do the job described above and use it where ever the situation fits not just database backup.

Any good ideas ? : )

Comment: The only thing making a thread "daemon" will do is tell the VM not to stay alive if it's the only thread left.  So they would not help in your case, where the VM is obviously being killed already.  What you're looking for is to daemonize the Java process itself, which has nothing to do with using daemon threads within the Java process.

Comment: Hmm..then how do I make a programme that does some jobs on the background at a specified time interval ?

Comment: @PerfectGundam a non-daemon thread!

Comment: @PerfectGundam: Investigate making your Java program a service.  It doesn't seem like you really want it to be governed by the SSH session at all.  For example, Linux has `upstart` or initd.  You can write a minimal script to execute and daemonize a process on certain triggers, like startup and shutdown.  And you can manually start/stop the service as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**, you have to launch your program in a special way, and you have (at least) two options: `nohup` or `screen`.

Let's now discuss why and how each one works.

---

### `nohup`

Java's *daemon threads* is not what you are looking for, they have nothing to do with the issue. You can use normal threads (or even a single-threaded java program). You just need to change the way you launch your java program.

I have many executable jars that run as "daemons" on a bunch of servers, and I made a simple launch script that prepares the environment and makes it possible to terminate the SSH connection without stopping it. The main part is how to invoke the JVM: you use **nohup**.

```
nohup java -jar myfile.jar > stdout.log &
```

From nohup's man,

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

So, when you terminate your SSH connection, it will send SIGHUP to all processes it started which would terminate them as you are observing. With `nohup`, however, your process is immune to it.

Also, note that I redirect the standard output to a file called `stdout.log`. This is done so that you can see whatever your program writes to STDOUT (generally some logging information that would be useful for debugging).

To terminate your program, you can use `jps` to list the `PID` of your process (say it's `123`), then call `kill 123`. Note that for this to work your program needs to correctly handle this kind of shutdown (which involves adding a shutdown hook with `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)` which will terminate all the threads you launched).

If, for whatever reason (a bug, or you didn't implement a graceful shutdown), the program won't terminate after issuing the `kill` command (which sends the process a `SIGTERM`), you can change the signal it sends to `SIGKILL` with `kill -9 123`, which will simply destroy the process. Mind that this can be as dangerous as a power failure (ie, suppose you are in the middle of the `try` block of a `try {} finally {}` -- your `finally` block will not execute!).

---

### `screen`

There's an alternative, which is to use `SCREEN`. With it, you launch a shell that is also immune to shutdowns, and that you can share among many connections. To use it, connect to your server, and then:

```
screen -R
```

A new shell will start, in which you run your java program as normal:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

To make it go to the background, just press `ctrl+a ctrl+d`. To bring it back to the front, just execute `screen -R` again. If you wish to terminate your program, you could do so by entering the `screen` session again and pressing `ctrl+c` (if your java program correctly deals with this kind of shutdown).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot ! I guess I was going into the wrong direction !

Comment: Glad it was helpful! And, yes, this is somewhat confusing... "daemon services" vs "daemon threads", they seem related concepts, but they are quite different!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities for scheduled tasks, in order from least to most complex, are the [TimerTask](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/) and the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/).  Both offer the option to cancel/delete the scheduled job.

Comment: Thanks, your answer also helps me quite a lot :)